# How to combine Risk, Catan, and Monopoly?

Tags: house-rules, catan, monopoly, risk

So my group of friends play a lot of Catan. And we recently got a version of Risk. We ended up thinking about how relationship destroying a combined version of Risk, Catan, and Monopoly would be.

So is there any way to combine the three? (Doesn't matter how mundane or ridiculous it is.)

Comment: What are you, a divorce attorney?

Comment: You can combine them by putting all of the pieces together in a large plastic bag and then throwing it away.

Comment: Use monopoly board. 2 Catan sets, place "producation markers (eg 2-12) randomly on all spaces. Can produce armies only where monopoly piece is after roll, if uncontrolled or friendly. Get resources based on owned spaces. Monopolies provide continent bonii. Leave lots of vague rules so maximum chance to come to blows.

Comment: Just this question alone, with some shoddy photoshop graphics and the promise of elaborate miniatures as stretch goals, is an easy $2 million+ kickstarter :P

Answer (score 2):

```
10 PLAY Catan
20 IF RND<0.5 GOTO 10
30 PLAY Risk
40 GOTO 10
50 PLAY Monopoly
```

Despite first appearances, this algorithm is not faulty.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine them into a triatlon.

- First play risk
- Next Monopoly
- Last Catan

But if you really want to combine them into one game:

- Use a hex tile based board like catan.
- Each player has a playing piece that starts at the first settlement and travels along your road (and ships).
- The first player that builds a settlement adjacent to an hex can buy it for two ore and a grain. You place an army on that hex.
- Each other player that builds a settlement adjacent to an hex owned by another player must pay one ore to the owner.
- If you own a hex, you can build an additional army for one ore and one grain.
- On your turn, you could use your army to conquer the hex owned by another player.

That combines elements of Risk, Monopoly and Catan and probably results in a game that is hard to play. But as always, be carefull what you ask for.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would handle this, but it requires at least four players. You also won't be able to do this with more players than the maximum of any game (i.e.: if the maximum player limit on your version of Catan is 4, you can't do this with five players).

What you'll need: a 60-second sand timer and all three games.

You're essentially going to be playing parallel games, rotating turn order in the same direction on each board. The fourth (and fifth and sixth, if available) player, who is not the main player on any board, will be the referee to make sure there's no funny business and to make die rolls on the Risk board. Turn order would look something like this:

1. P1 on Catan; P2 on Monopoly; P3 on Risk; P4 ref
2. P2 on Catan; P3 on Monopoly; P4 on Risk; P1 ref
3. P3 on Catan; P4 on Monopoly; P1 on Risk; P2 ref
4. P4 on Catan; P1 on Monopoly; P2 on Risk; P3 ref
5. Back to step 1

Each player takes their turn on their main board. Risk turns generally take the longest, so that's why the ref moves to Risk; they'll already have a sense of the board state. When necessary, the ref will also roll dice against the main players, which will mostly be happening in Risk.

If an action by a main player requires a main player from another board, grab the sand timer. The players have 60 seconds to finish that task, whether it's trading in Catan, or payment in Monopoly. During these 60-second interruptions, all play should be suspended on any board where the action isn't taking place. At the end of 60 seconds, if the action isn't completed (e.g.: a trade isn't agreed upon), the action is cancelled and can't be repeated again that turn.

At the end of the game, you have up to three winners, one for each of the boards. You also have no friends, but that's a different issue.

---

Note that this technique could technically be implemented with other games where:

1. Player interaction is fairly limited
2. People take complete turns before the next player
3. Turn order doesn't vary between rounds

Wanna throw Ticket to Ride in instead of Monopoly? That'll work. Not a big fan of Catan? Try out Candy Land instead.

Comment: This doesn't really combine the games, it's just playing all three games simultaneously. I'm not even convinced it would be any faster, since all games move at the pace of the slowest one, and all three games have to stop when any one does. It also removes a lot of the player interaction in trading resources or property, or forming alliances.

Comment: @Matt Agreed, but since they work on very different mechanics, "combining" in the sense of creating one board game doesn't really make sense. I'm taking "combining" to mean creating a system where all three games and their mechanics are used simultaneously.

Comment: @Matt As far as speed goes, playing a slow game of any of these would still be faster then playing them in tandem. And when someone realized they couldn't win on one of the boards, they might focus less when they are the main player there, taking the extra time to think about strategy on the other boards. This would speed up future turns as the field on each board winnows to a few potential winners.